# Pagination not working with query_posts

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I trying to add pagination to my WordPress website, it's working fine with blog page, but with custom category when click any link of pagination URL change, but content still the same.

**Custom category code**

```
        <?php query_posts('category_name=sport');

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // конец цикла
        else: echo '<p>Blank.</p>'; endif; ?>   

       <?php pagination(); ?>
```

**Pagintion in function.php**

```
function pagination() {
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999;
$links = paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big,'%#%',esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))), 
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'type' => 'array', 
    'prev_text'    => 'Назад',
    'next_text'    => 'Вперед',
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'show_all'     => false, 
    'end_size'     => 4, 
    'mid_size'     => 4,
    'add_args'     => false,
    'add_fragment' => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number' => ''
));
if( is_array( $links ) ) {
    echo '<ul class="pagination">';
    foreach ( $links as $link ) {
        if ( strpos( $link, 'current' ) !== false ) echo "<li class='active'>$link</li>"; 
        else echo "<li>$link</li>"; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
 }
```

}

Please help

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of: `query_posts('category_name=sport');`

try this:

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'sport',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => $page
);

query_posts($args);
```

For further customization check the [List of Query Vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'  in category_name='sport'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged'          => $paged,
  'category_name' => 'sport'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code:

```
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'work',
                'categories'=>'sports',
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'paged' => $page,
            );
            query_posts($args);

   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      <?php endwhile; 
      else: echo '<p>Blank.</p>'; endif; ?> 
     <?php pagination(); ?>
```

You have to mention `post type` also as per the example

Hope this work for you.